# How to configure SFTP to login in the "/" directory?

Tags: root, chroot, sftp

I want to login as root and make the / as the default directory in SFTP. Newbie help needed

Comment: As a friendly advice from a more experienced user: please don't and follow the standard method. It is proven to work and it is secure. You can use this as a reference: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSSH/Cookbook/SFTP

Answer (score 8):

### Warning: This method might be unsafe for server users.

Ubuntu doesn't allow root user and also login in ssh as root by default.

So the first thing you have to do is to enable your root user account:

```
$ sudo passwd root
```

Now you have got your root account enabled now.

I am not sure whether you have installed your OpenSSH server or not.

So I will teach you how to install OpenSSH server.

```
$ sudo apt-get install openssh-server
```

Now you are able to edit the ssh config:

```
$ sudo vi /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

Find the line contains "PermitRootLogin no", modify it to "PermitRootLogin yes".

Oh yeah, now restart the ssh server:

```
$ sudo service ssh restart
```

Now give it a try

Comment: Thanks. I edited the /etc/passwd file to change the root's home directory..

Comment: every road leads to rome,right?

Comment: I can confirm this works. but in my opinion, yes it is unsafe